# How do I accurately make a 14 tooth gear in Blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, 3d-printing

**I want to recreate this gear in Blender.**

[image]

- As you can see, there are 14 teeth on this gear.
- Tracing the shape with vertices is not an option as it needs to be exact.
  .

Comment: Hello :). Try to search this site, I believe there are some questions about modeling tank wheels... Also a more high-res image would be helpful :)

Comment: what part of the gear do you need? the inner circle + the 14 branch star? please highlight exactly what you want

Comment: Tank track? Could I ask what model?

Answer (score 6):

Figures with a recurrent shape that pivots around a center are easily generated with the spin tool in the edit mode of the 3D viewport. However, since it seems like you might benefit from "editability" of the shape I would suggest a different approach.

1. Mirror a cube and model a single gear tooth.
2. Add an Array modifier to the object.
3. Set its count to 14.
4. Add an empty object where you want the center of the gear
5. Rotate this empty by 360/14 (Blender will automatically calculate the outcome of that fraction)
6. Set the array only to "Object Offset" and select the empty.

The result should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't give enough details, but you could begin with a 28 vertex circle:

[image]

Extrude inwards if you want the inner circle that we can see on your photo. For the star shape itself, checker deselect to only select 14 of the 28 vertices:

[image]

Scale up or down:

[image]

Select all and bevel the vertices as much as you want:

[image]

Extrude up:

[image]

Extrude and scale inwards with a constraint on the Z axis:

[image]